# What if the utf-8 encoding html file contains a non-utf-8 character?

Tags: python, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm trying BeautifulSoup for parsing html files which is encoded in UTF-8. But unfortunately, this html file contains a few characters which are non-utf-8 character, hence not showed correctly. But this is OK for me since I could just simply skip these characters.

The problems is, even if I directly specify the encodingFrom as utf-8:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup (html,fromEncoding='utf-8')
```

It turns out the soup.originalEncoding is set to default windows-1252 automatically.

```
print soup.originalEncoding
windows-1252
```

I referred to the BeautifulSoup Documents and it's written like:

```
Beautiful Soup tries the following encodings, in order of priority, to turn your document into Unicode:

 - An encoding you pass in as the fromEncoding argument to the soup
   constructor.
 - An encoding discovered in the document itself
 - An encoding sniffed by looking at the first few bytes of the file. If
   an encoding is detected at this stage, it will be one of the UTF-*
   encodings, EBCDIC, or ASCII.
 - An encoding sniffed by the chardet library, if you have it installed.
 - UTF-8
 - Windows-1252
```

It seems it should use fromEncoding I specified instead of falling to the last one in the list.

Here is  [the original html I'm parsing](http://book.douban.com/tag/%E5%B0%8F%E8%AF%B4?start=80&type=R) for your reference.

Comment: @joelgoldstick , I would say the intentional encoding should be utf-8 (from the header part of the html). But it's possible that in this file, it contains some characters does not fall in utf-8 encoding (but most probably windows-1252). That could be the reason. But I would prefer just get the utf-8 part and omit the windows-1252 part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what the encoding of file will be, try decoding your string before passing it to BeautifulSoup and explicitly ignore non-utf8 characters.

```
unicode_html = myfile.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup (unicode_html)
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you refer to seems to be generally UTF-8 encoded but contains some byte sequences that cannot appear in UTF-8 encoded data. They probably result from incorrect code conversions or from insertion of data in another encoding. But it is “only” content data.

UTF-8 is “self-synchronizing,” so if you just skip the erroneous bytes, things should be fine for the rest – and as soon as you get to HTML markup, everything is in the ASCII range. Markup-significant character always appear as single bytes less that 0x80.

Comment: I agree, but I couldn't find a solution in using beautifulsoup. Whatever the encoding you specified (fromEncoding), it always falls to windows-1252 since there are some byte sequences cannot appear in UTF-8 encoded data.